# Correct Interpretation of the law of large numbers

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

Suppose I have an experiment where I toss a coin $100$ times, for example. My expectation value would be equal number of heads and tails, since that result has the highest probability compared to any other individual outcome.

Now, I have the two following scenarios :

I perform this experiment of tossing a $100$ coins infinite time. Does the law of large numbers say that as the number of experiments tend towards infinity, the total number of heads and tails that I got across all the experiments tend to be equal. Is this correct ?

Or does it mean that if I toss a single coin an infinite number of times, I'd get equal number of heads and tails.

Can someone tell me which one is correct, and in the case that both of them are wrong, point out the flaw in my understanding ?

Comment: @Michael what I meant was I'd expect to find equal number of heads and tails, not that expectation value is the sum of both.

Comment: It is quite unlikely to find an equal number of heads and tails, and in fact it is impossible if the number of flips is odd.  As the number of flips goes to infinity, we expect there to be an ever-growing gap between the number of heads and tails, in the sense that $E[|Heads - Tails|]$ grows to infinity.  However, that gap grows sublinearly with the total number of flips.  The law of large numbers talks about averages, not about sum totals.

Comment: If we flip a fair coin $n$ times the variance behaves as follows: \begin{align}  Var(Heads-Tails) &= n\\ Var\left(\frac{Heads-Tails}{n}\right) &= 1/n\end{align}